# Using data from an API for conditional rendering in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm buiding an application that receives foreign exchange currency pairs e.g EURUSD with their respective prices e.g EURUSD AskPrice: 0.90345 BidPrice: 0.90365 . The user of the application is supposed to set the price in a textInput at which they would like to be alerted once that price is reached. I have tried creating a function for this but it logs the input price immediately instead of checking the condition first and then waiting for the condition to be met first before logging. Below is the Code:

```
//Datafetching
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect}from 'react'
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import axios from '../utils/axios'

const CurrencyContext = createContext();

const CurrencyProvider =(props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const fetchpairs = async() => {
                const results = await axios.get('/v3/accounts/101-004-14328428-002/pricing?instruments=AUD_CAD%2CAUD_CHF%2CAUD_JPY%2CAUD_NZD%2CAUD_USD%2CCAD_CHF%2CCAD_JPY%2CCHF_JPY%2CEUR_AUD%2CEUR_CAD%2CEUR_CHF%2CEUR_GBP%2CEUR_NOK%2CEUR_NZD%2CEUR_USD%2CGBP_AUD%2CGBP_CAD%2CGBP_CHF%2CGBP_USD%2CGBP_JPY%2CNZD_CAD%2CNZD_CHF%2CNZD_JPY%2CUSD_CAD%2CUSD_JPY%2CUSD_CHF%2CUSD_ZAR%2CUSD_MXN')
                setData(results.data)
                setIsloading(false)
            }
            fetchpairs() 
        },1000)
      }, []);

      if(isLoading) {
        return (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
        )
    }else
    return (
        <CurrencyContext.Provider
        value={{
            data,
            setData,
            isLoading,
            setIsloading
        }}>
            {props.children}

        </CurrencyContext.Provider>

       
    )
}

export {CurrencyProvider, CurrencyContext}
```

//HomeScreen

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TextInput, ToastAndroid, Picker, Alert } from 'react-native'
import {ListItem, Card, Button, Icon} from 'react-native-elements'
import {ActionSheet} from 'native-base'
//import CurrencyPair from '../../CurrencyPair'
import {firebase} from '../../../firebase/config'
import {CurrencyContext} from '../../../context/Context'
import styles from '../HomeScreen/styles'



function HomeScreen({navigation, props}) {

    const currency = useContext(CurrencyContext);
    //hook for the modal
    const [modalopen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
//hook for the clicked currency pair
    const [clickedindex, setClickedIndex]  = useState(0)
//hook for the actionsheet
   const[sheet, setSheet] = useState(null)
   //Hooks for the alert
   const [pricealert, setPricealert] = useState('')



//function for checking alert condition

  const checkAlertCondition = (pricealert) => {
    if(pricealert >= {...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk} ){
      setPricealert(pricealert)
      console.log("Price" + pricealert + "has been hit")
    }
    else if(pricealert <=  {...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk})
    {
      setPricealert(pricealert)
      console.log("Price" + pricealert + "has been hit")

    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Set your alert price")
  
    }
  }
        //toast method that will be called when the ok button is called
    const showToastWithGravityAndOffset = () => {
      ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(
        "Alert created successfully",
        ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
        25,
        50
      );
    };
    const BUTTONS = [
      { text: "SMS", icon: "chatboxes", iconColor: "#2c8ef4" },
      { text: "Email", icon: "analytics", iconColor: "#f42ced" },
      { text: "Push Notification", icon: "aperture", iconColor: "#ea943b" },
      { text: "Delete", icon: "trash", iconColor: "#fa213b" },
      { text: "Cancel", icon: "close", iconColor: "#25de5b" }
    ];
    const DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX = DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX;
    const CANCEL_INDEX = CANCEL_INDEX;
return (
        <ScrollView>
          <Modal
          visible={modalopen}
          animationType={"fade"}
          >
            <View style={styles.modal}>
              <View>
                <Text style={{textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold"}}>
               {currency.data.prices[clickedindex].instrument}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
              {currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk}/{currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutBid}
              </Text>
              <Card.Divider/>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                
                    <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          value={pricealert}
          onChangeText = {(pricealert) => setPricealert(pricealert)}
          placeholder="Alert Price"
          placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
          numeric
          keyboardType='decimal-pad'    
        />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputWrap}> 
                </View>

              </View>   
          <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={() =>
            ActionSheet.show(
              {
                options: BUTTONS,
                cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
                destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
                title: "How do you want to receive your notification"
              },
              buttonIndex => {
                setSheet({ clicked: BUTTONS[buttonIndex] });
              }
            )}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            <Text>ActionSheet</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
               onPress={() => {setModalOpen(false); checkAlertCondition(pricealert);showToastWithGravityAndOffset();} }>
                <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>OK</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        <Card>
            <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                Welcome
            </Text>
            <Button title="Sign Out" type="outline" onPress ={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}/>
            <Button title="My Alerts"  onPress ={() =>navigation.navigate("AlertScreen") }/>
            
        </Card>

        <View>
            {currency.data.prices && currency.data.prices.map((prices, index) => {
                return (
      <ListItem
        key={index}
        onPress = {() => {setModalOpen(true);setClickedIndex(index);}} 
        bottomDivider>
        <ListItem.Content>
            <ListItem.Title>
            {currency.data.prices[index].instrument}        {currency.data.prices[index].closeoutAsk}         {currency.data.prices[index].closeoutBid}
            </ListItem.Title>
        </ListItem.Content>
      </ListItem>     
                )
            })
}
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
)
}
export default HomeScreen
```

[image]

Comment: what is `currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk`

Comment: Its an index that is used to refer a selected item `{currency.data.prices[index].closeoutAsk}` in the listItem when a modal is opened

Comment: what is closeoutAsk ? is it a decimal number?

Comment: yes. Its a decimal number

Comment: `{...currency.data.prices[clickedindex].closeoutAsk}` then why are you trying to deconstruct the decimal number?

Comment: To easily assign it an index

Comment: Let me attach a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

inside onPress you are calling `checkAlertCondition` but with no params yet inside that function you are expecting the `pricealert` also you are trying to use >= with the left hand side being an object.

Try this:

```
const checkAlertCondition = (pricealert) => {
  if(currency.data.prices[clickedindex].AskPrice >= pricealert){
    setPricealert(pricealert)
    console.log("Price" + pricealert + "has been hit")
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the `pricealert` parameter. Its now logging the price that the user inputs in the textinput instead of first fulfiling the condition first.

Comment: update your question code please, also what does this `console.log("Price" + pricealert + "has been hit")` log?

Comment: It logs `pricealert` from this textInput:                                                              `<TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          value={pricealert}
          onChangeText = {(pricealert) => setPricealert(pricealert)}
          placeholder="Alert Price"
          placeholderTextColor="#60605e"
          numeric
          keyboardType='decimal-pad' 
        />`

Comment: I have updated my answer. But I am going a bit blind here. You should do a code snippet so I can debug.